# Plotting geoJSON Tracks Across Dateline without Errant Lines with Cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, geopandas, cartopy

I am producing a world map with ship tracks provided in geoJSON - when the track crosses the 180/-180 line I get an errant line across the world. To simplify things I've reduced the tracks.json file to a singular track but the usual file has multiple ship tracks.

The plot is then saved as a world map with no borders at 4000x2000 pixels resolution - see:

https://www.oceanic.udel.edu/globaldataview/rt_content/ships/latest/ship_locations.jpg

[image: Plot image showing the errant line]

```
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

def main():

    tracks = gpd.read_file('https://www.researchvessels.org/data/tracks.json')

    fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(40, 20), frameon=False)
    plt.axis('off')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_axis_off()
    tracks.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow")
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    # Background Image below is available via https://www.researchvessels.org/data/nasa_bm_default.jpg
    img = plt.imread('c:/scripts/NASA_BM_default.jpg')
    img_extent = (-180, 180, -90, 90)
    ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), aspect='auto')
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
    fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the tracks plotted correctly, you need to sanitize the values of `longitude` in the tracks that cross dateline.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

def sanitize_lonlist(lons):
    new_list = []
    oldval = 0
    # used to compare with the adjacent longitudes
    # and values exceed, disconnect linestring
    treshold = 10   
    for ix,ea in enumerate(lons):
        diff = oldval - ea
        if (ix>0):
            if (diff>treshold):
                ea = ea+360
        oldval = ea
        new_list.append(ea)
    return new_list

tracks = gpd.read_file('https://www.researchvessels.org/data/tracks.json')
# grab x and y of the first geometry object
xs = tracks.geometry[0].xy[0]
ys = tracks.geometry[0].xy[1]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
ax.set_global() 
ax.coastlines()

# plot the geometry using sanitized values
ax.plot(sanitize_lonlist(xs), ys, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='red', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: shiptrack]